# Developing a feature for a joomla component

Tags: php, joomla, routes, virtuemart

Hi im trying to add a feature to a Joomla component and i don't know the `Routing` of joomla very well, i know it is bad practice to use for example `_construct` method of the main php file of the component to implement my need, but i don't know a better way tho.

As i found out routing in joomla is a bit complicated i mean there is buncha switch case stuff there and semi complicated things happening i followed one route and it was massive returning to Routing.php several times. I don't know how to implement mine btw and be exclusive while doing that i mean be the only one who triggered while calling the route.

I have a laravel background so i know MVC but this one is heavy.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, for example using plugin hooks, template overrides, layout overrides, custom modules or components...
but your demand is really too general to be more precise than this.

Comment: I once asked a very specified question but it had no answers at least this one has a comment, i don't want waste my time reading joomla documents, actually deadline is so near i just wanted to see if there is a normal route thing to do i want to add a `to test` feature for the virtuemart cart. I traced the code and decided to do it with Ajax so view would be only on JS side and on php i just use `_constract` or general part of a component and check if my route triggered and after done i put `die()` with appropriate `http` header this is actually annoying but working.

Comment: This is a one page doc which I think might help you https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component. Also a small advice if you don't know swimming it is dangerous to dive in sea.

Comment: Please elaborate your need, for adding any feature in an existing Joomla Component, you can use dispatchers(triggers) by creating your own plugin. There is no need to get into routing for that. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what @Anant said i decided to write plugins. I asked my exact question [here](http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=140706.0) on the forum of the VirtueMart, Cause as i said in the comments i once asked it [here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/23225/having-new-payment-method-option-in-virtuemart-as-free-for-test) and had no answer or even views was very low. List of virtuemart triggers is [here](https://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=101629.msg476096#msg476096)